# NaNs suddenly appearing for sklearn KFolds

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I'm trying to run cross validation on my data set. The data appears to be clean, but then when I try to run it, some of my data gets replaced by NaNs. I'm not sure why. Has anybody seen this before?

```
y, X = np.ravel(df_test['labels']), df_test[['variation', 'length', 'tempo']]
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = cv.train_test_split(X,y,test_size=.30, random_state=4444)
```

This is what my X data looked like before KFolds:

    `variation   length  tempo
0   0.005144    1183.148118 135.999178
1   0.002595    720.165442  117.453835
2   0.008146    397.500952  112.347147
3   0.005367    1109.819501 172.265625
4   0.001631    509.931973  135.999178
5   0.001620    560.365714  151.999081
6   0.002513    763.377778  107.666016
7   0.009262    502.083628  99.384014
8   0.000610    500.017052  143.554688
9   0.000733    269.001723  117.453835`

My Y data looks like this:

`array([ True, False, False,  True,  True,  True,  True, False,  True, False], dtype=bool)`

Now when I try to do the cross val:

```
kf = KFold(X_train.shape[0], n_folds=4, shuffle=True)

for train_index, val_index in kf:
    cv_train_x = X_train.ix[train_index]
    cv_val_x = X_train.ix[val_index]
    cv_train_y = y_train[train_index]
    cv_val_y = y_train[val_index]
    print cv_train_x

    logreg = LogisticRegression(C = .01)
    logreg.fit(cv_train_x, cv_train_y)
    pred = logreg.predict(cv_val_x)
    print accuracy_score(cv_val_y, pred)
```

When I try to run this, I error out with the below error, so I add the print statement.
`ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').`

In my print statement, this is what it printed, some data became NaNs.

   `variation       length       tempo
0        NaN          NaN         NaN
1        NaN          NaN         NaN
2   0.008146   397.500952  112.347147
3   0.005367  1109.819501  172.265625
4   0.001631   509.931973  135.999178`

I'm sure I'm doing something wrong, any ideas? As always, thank you so much!

Comment: please provide **whole** code, I am pretty sure you omitted part that causes the error

Comment: I didn't omit anything, though the data I put in the question is just a snippet of it.

Comment: so you do not have **any lines** after the print statement?

Comment: Ah, yes, I do, but it's just the algorithm I'm trying to run Kfolds on.

    logreg = LogisticRegression(C = .01)    
    logreg.fit(cv_train_x, cv_train_y)    
    pred = logreg.predict(cv_val_x)    
    print accuracy_score(cv_val_y, pred)

Sorry, I don't know how to make the code look like code, and it can't enter the algorithm because of the NaNs, so it errors when it tries to fit.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the error. Please try to create minimal reproducing example, data + code that actually shows this error.

Comment: I updated the question with a subset of the data, I reran and errored on this subset as well. Thank you so much for helping me look into this lejlot! Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To solve use `.iloc` instead of `.ix` to index your pandas dataframe

```
for train_index, val_index in kf:
    cv_train_x = X_train.iloc[train_index]
    cv_val_x = X_train.iloc[val_index]
    cv_train_y = y_train[train_index]
    cv_val_y = y_train[val_index]
    print cv_train_x

    logreg = LogisticRegression(C = .01)
    logreg.fit(cv_train_x, cv_train_y)
    pred = logreg.predict(cv_val_x)
    print accuracy_score(cv_val_y, pred)
```

Indexing with `ix` is usually equivalent to using `.loc` which is **label based** indexing, not **index based**. While `.loc` works on `X` which has a nice integer based indexing/labeling, after cv split this rule is no longer there, you get something like:

```
        length       tempo  variation
4   509.931973  135.999178   0.001631
2   397.500952  112.347147   0.008146
7   502.083628   99.384014   0.009262
6   763.377778  107.666016   0.002513
5   560.365714  151.999081   0.001620
3  1109.819501  172.265625   0.005367
9   269.001723  117.453835   0.000733
```

and now you **no longer have** label 0 or 1, so if you do

```
X_train.loc[1]
```

you will get an Exception

```
KeyError: 'the label [1] is not in the [index]'
```

However, pandas has a **silent error** if you request multiple labels, where **at least one exists**. Thus if you do

```
 X_train.loc[[1,4]]
```

you will get

```
       length       tempo  variation
1         NaN         NaN        NaN
4  509.931973  135.999178   0.001631
```

As expected - 1 returns NaNs (since it was not found) and 4 represents actual row - since it is inside X_train. In order to solve it - just switch to `.iloc` or manually rebuild an index of X_train.

Comment: Thank you so much lejlot, that fixed it. Really appreciate the time and the help!