# how to check nan for panda column values which are lists in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, vectorization

I have a Panda dataframe which a column contains values of lists. I'm feeding one of the column values to a kfold.

```
filtered_labels = filtered_df['labels']
filtered_sentences = filtered_df.drop('labels', axis=1)

kf = KFold(n_splits=5) # Define the split - into 5 folds 
kf.get_n_splits(filtered_sentences)

for train_index, test_index in kf.split(filtered_sentences.shape[0]):
    X_train, X_test = filtered_sentences.loc[train_index,filtered_sentences.columns], filtered_sentences.loc[test_index,filtered_sentences.columns]
    y_train, y_test = filtered_labels[train_index], filtered_labels[test_index]

    tdif_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(max_df=5,norm='l2',smooth_idf=True,use_idf=True,ngram_range=(1,1))

    train_corpus_as_string = [get_string_representation_from_tokens(sentence_tokens)
                                for sentence_tokens in X_train['setenceTokens']]

    tdif_train_features = tdif_vectorizer.fit_transform(train_corpus_as_string)
         tdif_test_features = tdif_vectorizer.transform(X_test) 

    vModel = LogisticRegression()
    vModel.fit(tdif_train_features,y_train)
    tdif_predicted_data_set = vModel.predict(tdif_test_features)
```

When i print the content it shows as below,

```
X_train, X_test = filtered_sentences.loc[train_index,filtered_sentences.columns], filtered_sentences.loc[test_index,filtered_sentences.columns]

X_train['setenceTokens']

Out[642]: 
2171     [catastrophic, effect, hiroshima, nagasaki, at...
2172     [iraq, catastrophic, need, replace, constant, ...
2173          [learn, legacy, catastrophic, eruption, via]
2174     [catastrophic, effect, hiroshima, nagasaki, at...
2175              [wish, go, custom, werent, catastrophic]
2176     [best, part, old, baseball, manager, wear, uni...
2177               [learn, event, u, history, year, later]
2178     [catastrophic, effect, hiroshima, nagasaki, at...
2179     [catastrophic, effect, hiroshima, nagasaki, at...
2180              [society, respond, crisis, catastrophic]
2181     [british, upper, class, cause, catastrophic, s...
2182                   [dear, anyone, family, alive, 2040]
2183     [scientist, believe, catastrophic, manmade, gl...
2184     [everything, seem, catastrophic, feel, bad, hi...
2185     [jim, blog, catastrophic, outcome, may, come, ...
2186     [u, want, lead, united, state, catastrophic, w...
2187                  [stop, extreme, hurt, middle, class]
2188     [learn, legacy, catastrophic, eruption, new, y...
2189          [learn, legacy, catastrophic, eruption, via]
2190     [catastrophic, effect, hiroshima, nagasaki, at...
2191            [good, look, catastrophic, rain, flooding]
...
```

Since these values are in list of lists i want to convert them to an array of following format, ['society, respond, crisis, catastrophic','something, catastrophic, come, tune'..] so that I can provide it to my tdif_vectorizer.fit_transform(array_of_strings).

When iterating the tokens using following ,

```
train_corpus_as_string = [get_string_representation_from_tokens(sentence_tokens)
                        for sentence_tokens in X_train['setenceTokens']]
```

in the function I print the list I'm getting and I get nan as a value. please see below,

```
....
['escape', 'place', 'hide', 'time', 'space', 'collide']
['niggra', 'first', 'time', 'hear', 'song', 'sky', 'collide']
['even', 'star', 'moon', 'collide', 'oh', 'oh', 'never', 'want', 'back', 'life', 'take', 'word']
nan

and error : TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

following is my get_string_representation_from_tokens method,

```
def get_string_representation_from_tokens(tokens):
    string_tokens = ""
    print(tokens)
    for token in tokens:
        string_tokens += str(token) + " "
    return string_tokens
```

My end goal is run kfold of 5 times and get the training data , and use a TfidfVectorizer to get the vectors and provide to a logistic regression model and predict the values.  TfidfVectorizer expects data to be in a array of strings. that's why i'm iterating the above list of lists to get the desired array as I mentioned above.

How can I check whether a value is nan and assign a empty string. I tried many methods but not successful .

**Question two**

I'm trying to create a sample so that it's easy to run the idea, but I have a separate question (pardon me for asking this at the end). Problem lies here when I split data it introduces nan values,

my original dataframe column values does not have any null/nan values because see below,

```
filtered_sentences.isnull().sum()
Out[652]: 
setenceTokens    0
dtype: int64
```

But when I split using following line ,

```
X_train, X_test = filtered_sentences.loc[train_index,filtered_sentences.columns], filtered_sentences.loc[test_index,filtered_sentences.columns]
```

and X_train contains null/nan values,see below

```
X_train.isnull().sum()
Out[653]: 
setenceTokens    21
dtype: int64
```

there are 21 values. I saw a similar question in [NaNs suddenly appearing for sklearn KFolds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39376967/nans-suddenly-appearing-for-sklearn-kfolds) but I used the same but still i'm getting nan values. If i can get pass this I do not need to check for values nan. sorry making the post so long .

Comment: This is probably an easy fix.  But please make it easier to help you by providing a [mcve].  Provide the `get_string_representation_from_tokens()` code, and real example data, and your expected output.

Comment: andrew i have edited my question. I have showed the outputs I'm getting. hope it helps to understand the question

Comment: That's a good start - but your input isn't really usable input, it's just the printout of your Series, which is truncated.  Can you just provide the full first few lines, and one case with `NA`, and the exact expected output?  Part of creating an MCVE is the idea that you don't need to provide your exact data - just give a toy use case that captures the issue you're having.  (You can use real data too, if it's easy enough, but a printout with `...` doesn't allow anyone else to use your code to reproduce the problem.)

Comment: I have put dots because it prints a huge list, since i'm printing print(tokens) in the method get_string_representation_from_tokens. What I have is panda data frame and I'm giving one of the columns values to kfold to split data, and every splitted data set i need to do above actions in the for loop. please see the content in for loop. I have already mentioned my expected output which is array of strings. Ill try to simplify the question more .

Comment: Please follow Andrew's advice and give us a complete toy example which we can run on our own computers and which exhibits the same problem. Otherwise, it's very difficult to try to guess where the problem lies.

Comment: andrew,IonicSolutions  I have updated the question. please see the end. I'll try to create a sample. but its hard to reproduce the behaviour i'm seeing in a toy sample.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. From this solution i'm not getting nan values. Issue was way i created the data frame. Earlier my dataframe had column values as arrays. like below

```
['feel','bad','literally','feel']
['feeling','heart','sinking']
```

but it should have values as

```
feel bad literally feel
feeling heart sinking
```

Then when I split from kfold it didn't gave me nan values. Hope this save time for someone.

Comment: `df.col_name.str.join(' ')`